# Plumbing fixture for draining spa shower lines when off?

Tags: plumbing

I am installing a spa shower, no tub.  Is there a device I can include at low points of the outputs to the raincan, etc, that will bleed the lines when the shower is off, exploiting that there is no pressure in those lines, kind of like a tub kit diverter?

Comment: I have heard of some installations of a diverter from the mixing valve to feed a spigot in the wall below a shower head. I think the purpose was to have a place to draw water into a bucket, but this would serve to drain the lines from a shower. Do these spa showers have a single mixing valve or multiple?

Comment: So, you want to automatically drain the lines when the shower is off. Why? And, is the shower valve **before** these lines, so that the pressure going to zero can trigger the automatic drain?

Comment: Yes, the shower valve is before these lines.  I think they ought to be drained because I’ve seen what filth grows in there especially when left sitting for a long time.  Since the outputs are not all on at once, they don’t automatically get ejected when the shower is getting up to temp - wouldn’t want to get hit with the nasty standing water mid-shower if I happened to change to an infrequently chosen setting.

Comment: The trouble with a manual spigot is that I would need one per output because my diverter is integrated into the controller and so there’s no single place to integrate such a device.  I’m hoping for three automatic ones draining out a single ~downspout.

Comment: I think I am looking for a “current to close” “control valve” product - one suited for residential plumbing sizes and pressures.

Comment: A “normally open check valve” at 2 psi or higher to close?  but I haven’t found that actual product available for purchase yet.

Answer (score -1):

Unless your talking a country mile of "standing" water in those pipes you can install ball valves above the faucet.